# Determine if points in table B are inside a polygon at table A using Oracle Spatial (Geometry fields are different)

Tags: plsql, gis, polygon, spatial, point

I have a problem! I'm new in Oracle Spatial, but I've been working with pl/sql for a while. The thing is, I need to identify points (x,y) from geometry attribute from table B, at or inside geometry attribute (polygons)  from table A. The issue: both tables have different data inside geometry field.

More details:
Getting the DDL from tables:

```
---------------------
--  DDL for Table A
---------------------
CREATE A 
(   
GEOMETRY MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY,
...
ENTITYID NUMBER,  
MANZENT VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
...
) 

CREATE INDEX A_IDX ON A (GEOMETRY)
INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;

--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table B
--------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE B 
(   ID_GIS NUMBER(8,0), 
GEOMETRY MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY,
...
) 

CREATE INDEX B_IDX ON B (GEOMETRY) 
INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;
```

Getting data from Table A, the format from attribute geometry is:

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(3002, NULL, NULL, MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1), MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(351059.668003312, 6283365.86125775, 0, 350989.900040253, 6283352.35005758, 0, 350945.450026879, 6283344.01994977, 0, 350942.789988843, 6283344.05999729, 0, 350941.519995767, 6283344.33999171, 0, 350939.949994132, 6283345.17999723, 0, 350938.640010838, 6283346.53002549, 0, 350937.800033809, 6283348.69002867, 0, 350932.586269235, 6283379.08172448, 0, 351052.837823787, 6283402.34153528, 0, 351059.668003312, 6283365.86125775, 0, 351059.668003312, 6283365.86125775, 0))
```

Getting data from Table A, the format from attribute geometry is:

```
MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 32719, MDSYS.SDO_POINT_TYPE(352761.049, 6287740.01, NULL), NULL, NULL)
```

Same structure but; obviously the data are different in both fields! I mean, the data type hosted!

When I run the script to determine the relation, it throw error:

```
SELECT A.entityid, B.manzent
  FROM A, B
  WHERE SDO_RELATE(A.geometry, B.geometry,
               'mask=COVERS') = 'TRUE';
```

Error:

> ORA-13295: geometry objects are in different coordinate systems
>   ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_3GL", line 4
>   ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD2", line 769
>   ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_3GL", line 155
>   13295. 00000 -  "geometry objects are in different coordinate systems"
>   *Cause:    An Oracle Spatial function was called with two geometries that have
>   different
>              SRIDs.
>   *Action:   Transform geometry objects to be in the same coordinate system and
>              call the spatial function.

In fact, it is like that ("geometry objects are in different coordinate systems"). Given the example.  I've been look for how to transform the data from table B...
 
I did this, I got the points from table B, but couldn't find how to determine if are inside the polygon at A table.

I've try with SDO_CONTAINS and SDO_RELATE, JOIN, etc.

I'm going to be truly thankful if you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

Looks Like different coordinate systems for two tables.

You can check it in your Metadata table.

Select SDO_SRID from MDSYS.SDO_GEOM_METADATA_TABLE WHERE SDO_TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_A';
Select SDO_SRID from MDSYS.SDO_GEOM_METADATA_TABLE WHERE SDO_TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE_B';

Both tables should be having same SRID for SDO operations.

Comment: The schema didn't recognice **SDO_GEOM_METADATA_TABLE**. I found **USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA**. The information from both tables (A & B) are different.  
---
TABLE: A  
COLUMN: GEOMETRY  
INFO: MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY(MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', -3701691.09411887, 590488.591781422, 5E-10), MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', 3911088.55477536, 7988320.84199649, 5E-10), MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Z', 0, 0, 5E-10))  
SRID:   
---
TABLE: B  
COLUMN: GEOMETRY  
INFO: MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY(MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', 88149, 590052, 1), MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', 3910959, 7988206, 1))  
SRID: 32719

Comment: Yes, then update Table A's SRID same as Table B : '32719'